# How can I update only a few tables using a pre-populated Core Data database via an App Store Update

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data, migration

We have an app in the app store right now that uses a pre-populated Core Data database. We want to update all the tables in the database, except for 1 table which is the Favorites table where users store their Favourite bus routes or stops. Currently, we are accomplishing this update having the app delegate use the SQLite C API, and NSFileManager to do the following:

1. Create a temporary Favorites database
2. Copy the favourites from the database on the disk to the temporary database
3. Delete the database on disk ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:storePath error:NULL] )
4. Copy the new database from the app bundle to disk ([fileManager copyItemAtPath:databaseBundlePath toPath:storePath error:&copyError])
5. Copy Favourites from the Temp database into the new database.
6. Delete the temporary Favorites database.

I was wondering if there was another way to do this because there have been a lot of complaints with our app crashing during the splash screen which is the time where the database copying happens.

I heard of Core Data Migration, but my understanding of Core Data Migration is that you can migrate data only when a the model changes, but in our case the model hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you leave the database as it is and just insert/remove the data into it as needed instead of copying a prefilled database?

Alternatively you can also take the opposite approach: leave the original database, copy the prefilled one with a new name, insert the favorites from the original database into the new one, remove the original one, and now only use the new one. Like this, you are always sure nothing happens to your user's favorites.

Or you could write the favorites first into a text file, and then do the same thing you describe. If anything happens (like a crash), you always still have the favorites in the saved text file.

It also may work with core data migration, but up to now I avoided that ... any structural database change is something I would rather avoid, I think ...